# How to filter UITableViewCell on two variables equalling eachother

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to populate a UITableView in Swift 4 and I want to just show records that belong to the user that is logged in. Obviously I require an `IF` statement to see whether two values are equal to each other. How do I return `null` as such, i.e. no cell is added to the table. Please see the code below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
    cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
    "RunCell") as? RunCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    let user_id_main = String(MainMenuViewController.myVariables.user_id.prefix(2))

    if (user_id_main==runs[indexPath.row].user_id)
    {
        cell.idLbl.text = "ID: " + runs[indexPath.row].run_id
        cell.dateLbl.text = "Date: " + runs[indexPath.row].date_of_run

        return cell
    }
    return cell
}
```

I know `return cell` outside of the `IF` still would return a cell, this is until I find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the way UITableViews work.  You can't decide on the fly if a cell is to be displayed or not.  You need to do that before the table is loaded or reloaded.

Before the tableView is loaded or reloaded, filter your array into a new array that just contains records with the matching `user_id`.  Then use this new array as the model for your table.  The size of the new array will determine the number of rows in the table, and each row will correspond to one item of your new array.

Every time the `user_id_main` changes, refilter your `runs` array and reload the table.

Comment: `self.runsFilter.append(self.runs)` I am trying to add to `runsFilter` but it is saying `Cannot convert value of type '[Run]' to expected argument type 'Run'`, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `self.runsFilter = self.runs.filter { $0.run_id == user_id_main }`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot return nil value cell,

**to achieve what you want, first filter your `runs` array for the values you required and store in other array say `mainUserRuns`, then use this new array to provide data for your tableview.**